# Problema con insert sqlite Android studio

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Hola tengo un problema al insertar datos a una tabla en `sqlite`, el problema es que solo me toma el primer `insert` que se ejecuta y si quiero añadir otro `insert` no me lo permite el código es el siguiente:

Clase conexion:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Conexion extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public  Conexion(Context context, String name, 
        SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(Clientes.CREAR_TABLA_CLIENTES);
        db.execSQL("insert into clientes values (111,'sergio','1',22)");
        db.execSQL("insert into clientes values (222,'juan','1',234)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Clientes.TABLA_CLIENTES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que realizas debe funcionar sin problema, insertar 2 registros:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(Clientes.CREAR_TABLA_CLIENTES);
        db.execSQL("insert into clientes values (111,'sergio','1',22)");
        db.execSQL("insert into clientes values (222,'juan','1',234)");
    }
```

el problema es que no se insertan los dos registros porque seguramente ya se creo la estructura de la tabla (seguramente tenías que solo insertara un registro) y solo puede volver a crearse nuevamente e insertar los registros con alguna de estas opciones:

- cambia el `versionCode` de la aplicación
- eliminas el caché de la aplicación
- eliminas la aplicación y vuelves a subirla a tu dispositivo.